# do not have output form url with CURL

Tags: php

Hi guys i use my code to get file data from url i tested the curl function worked as well but i dont know what problem with my code because i don't have any output pleas can some one tell me how to fix that my guess i have problem with this section:

```
foreach($serverlist as $line) { 
$line = trim($line);
```

but i don't know how to fix that:

```
<?php

function get_data($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$serverlist = get_data("http://185.49.84.109/iw5msl/serverinfo.txt");
$file_headers = @get_headers($serverlist);

if(($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found') || ($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 302 Found' && $file_headers[7] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'))
{ 
    echo "The server list is currently being changed due to some upgrades and therefore not available. Sorry for any inconvenience.";
} else {

$odd = false;
foreach($serverlist as $line) { 
$line = trim($line); 
list($name,$ip,$players,$map,$type,$mod,$country) = explode("|!|!|", $line . "|!|!|");
$ixp = explode(":", $ip);
if(in_array($ixp[0], file("data/servers.banlist")) || in_array($ip, file("data/servers.banlist"))) continue;
$type = parse_gametype($type);
$map = @$_MAPS["mw3"][$map];
if(strstr($map, "<") > -1) $map = "Server by idiot.";
list($players,$maxplayers) = explode("/", $players);
$country = "<span style=\"display:none\">$country</span><img alt=\"$country\" title=\"$country\" src=\"".parse_flag($country)."\" />";
?>
<tr style="height: 50px">
                            <td style="text-align:left"><span style="display: none"><?php echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", strip_tags($name)); ?></span>
                                <span style="font-size: 1.5em; font-family: 'Play', 'OCR A Extended'"><?php echo $name; ?></span><br />
                                <span style="font-size: 1.3em"><?php echo $ip; ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right; font-size: 1.5em"><?php echo $players; ?></td>
                            <td style="font-size: 1.5em">/</td>
                            <td style="text-align: left; font-size: 1.5em; width: 50px"><?php echo $maxplayers; ?></td>
                            <td style="font-family: Electrolize; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 1.4em; text-align:right; display: color:white;background-size:100%;background-position:center center;background-image:url(<?php echo $map_thumb; ?>)">
                                <div class="blackgradient gradient"><?php echo $map; ?></div>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $type; ?></td>
                            <!--<td><?php echo $mod; ?></td>-->
                            <td><?php echo $country; ?></td>
                        </tr>
<?php $odd = !$odd; ?>
<?php } ?>
                    </tbody></table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: curl doesn't return arrays. it returns the response as a STRING. you can't foreach() a string.

Comment: right and how to fix that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add

```
$serverlist=explode("\n", $serverlist);
```

Before the FOREACH line.

Thx, it should be `"\n"`.

For EMPTY LINE at tail, use that near the FOREACH:

```
$serverlist=explode("\n", $serverlist); //ADDED
$odd = false;
foreach($serverlist as $line) { 
$line = trim($line); 
if(empty($line))continue; //ADDED
```

Comment: `'`-quoted strings don't honor `\n`-type escape sequences. You need to use `"\n"`, which WILL be a newline char

Comment: now work but i have one extra line on my output how to fix that?

Comment: Check if the $line in foreach is empty, if empty act CONTINUE.

Comment: I added if($line == empty) continue; but just destroy everything :D pleas can you gimme the right code thanks

Comment: `($line == empty)` seems not correct in PHP. Use `empty($line)` instead as I updated.